# Display PHP output via Ajax under the button that was clicked--Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display PHP output via Ajax under the button that was clicked but my code is not working.

**output.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['click_me'])){
        echo "<p>Something</p>";
    }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="same-class" name = "click_me" type = "button">Button 1</button>
<p> To display below me</p>

<button class="same-class" type = "button">Button 2</button>
<p> To display below me too</p>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.same-class').click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').append('Hello'); //Works
        $.ajax({
            url: 'output.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {click_me: 1},
            success:function(response){
                $(this).next('p').append(response); //Does not work--does not do anything, does not produce errors either.

                console.log(response); // works
                $('same-class').append(response); //works but all buttons get appended
                alert(response); //works
            }

        });

    });
});
```

It appears that the position of `$(this)` inside the `success: function(response){}` is the cause of the problem. The code does not produce errors either. A lot of search I have made on SO and else suggests that this should work. More than 2 hours now, I can't figure out why it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The `$(this)` in your callback function refers to the object you pass in. So you need to save the refence to the button before you  make an ajax call.Update your javascript to below:

```
$(function(){
    $('.same-class').click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').append('Hello'); //Works
        //save a reference to the button clicked.
        var btn = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'output.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {click_me: 1},
            success:function(response){
               //use the button reference from above.
               btn.next('p').append(response); //Does not work--does not do anything, does not produce errors either.

                console.log(response); // works
                $('same-class').append(response); //works but all buttons get appended
                alert(response); //works
            }

        });

    });
});
```